# Using Python to concatenate to an empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I need to make a function that takes in an array of size (n,2) and outputs an array of size (n,7) after doing some calculations to make it that size.  I have the calculations working, but I can't seem to get the arrays to concatenate.  I've tried several versions and I either get an error, `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)` or it won't concatenate.

My code (which gets the error):

```
def function(x):
    P = np.empty([0, 7], dtype=float)
    #print("P" + str(P))
    for i in x:
        newP = np.array([1, i[0], i[0]**2, i[0]**3, i[1], i[1]**2, i[1]**3])
        #print("newP " + str(newP))
        np.concatenate((P, newP), axis=0)
        #print("P " + str(P))
    return P
```

Sample of the data being inputted:

```
-0.1724548709123342,-0.18110388871829428
1.8460643534931365,-0.6718568205279694
-0.6974409790449893,0.6034582863802577
0.7706652511875953,-0.564722201615943
```

EDIT
I've updated my code.  It no longer gets the error, but just doesn't add the two arrays, leaving the return array as [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

```
def series(x):
    #P = np.empty([1, 7], dtype=float)
    P = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    #print("P" + str(P))
    for i in x:
        newP = np.array([1, i[0], i[0]**2, i[0]**3, i[1], i[1]**2, i[1]**3])
        #print("newP " + str(newP))
        np.concatenate((P, newP), axis=0)
        #print("P " + str(P))
    print("P " + str(P))
    return P
```

Comment: Read the `concatenate` docs, and practice with the examples in an interactive session.  Also learn to check and change the number of dimensions of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have correct dimensions

```py
import numpy as np
x = [[-0.1724548709123342,-0.18110388871829428],
[1.8460643534931365,-0.6718568205279694],
[-0.6974409790449893,0.6034582863802577],
[0.7706652511875953,-0.564722201615943],]


def function(x):
    P = np.empty((1,7), dtype=float)
    #print("P" + str(P))
    for i in x:
        newP = np.array([1, i[0], i[0]**2, i[0]**3, i[1], i[1]**2, i[1]**3]).reshape(1,7)
        #print("newP " + str(newP), newP.shape, P.shape)
        P = np.concatenate((P, newP), axis=0)
        #print("P " + str(P))
    return P

function(x)
```

```
array([[ 1.00000000e+00,  1.72454871e-01,  2.97406825e-02,
         5.12892556e-03,  1.81103889e-01,  3.27986185e-02,
         5.93995736e-03],
       [ 1.00000000e+00, -1.72454871e-01,  2.97406825e-02,
        -5.12892556e-03, -1.81103889e-01,  3.27986185e-02,
        -5.93995736e-03],
       [ 1.00000000e+00,  1.84606435e+00,  3.40795360e+00,
         6.29130165e+00, -6.71856821e-01,  4.51391587e-01,
        -3.03270517e-01],
       [ 1.00000000e+00, -6.97440979e-01,  4.86423919e-01,
        -3.39251974e-01,  6.03458286e-01,  3.64161903e-01,
         2.19756518e-01],
       [ 1.00000000e+00,  7.70665251e-01,  5.93924929e-01,
         4.57717305e-01, -5.64722202e-01,  3.18911165e-01,
        -1.80096215e-01]])
```

NOTE: `np.empty` doesn't create an empty array, it creates an array with any values with that shape.

Comment: The x data cannot be changed.  I'm using the numbers in the x data to create a new array of size (n,7) based on the x data.  I made some changes based on your answer.  It's no longer giving me an error, but it just doesn't concatenate.  I've added an edit showing this in the question

Comment: @Stacey you are not storing the concatenated result  Use `P = np.concatenate((P, newP), axis=0)1`

Comment: But this frequent concatenation and assignment is not efficient. Either you use python `list` and use `append` or make an array of zeros and change the value.